# Unrecognized File Formats in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have some linux files with unrecognized file extensions and formats. One of the files have a "file1.sum.eepkg" extension and the other file have a "file2.tgz.eepkg". When i try to run the file command against the two files i get that their contents is data.

```
file file2.tgz.eepkg 
file2.tgz.eepkg: data
```

At the beginning i thought they are a ".pkg" format but when i tried using alien it said that it was an unknown type of package.

I am suspecting that there is some kind of encryption or encoding. Anyone has any ideas of things i might try next in order to figure out the contents of the file.

This is the hesdump of file1.sum.eepkg:

```
00000000  ee ef 2d 20 14 2d 06 2d  05 2d 00 00 74 02 69 00  |..- .-.-.-..t.i.|
00000010  00 6b 10 6d 00 76 db c7  db c4 57 36 17 f6 bf ef  |.k.m.v....W6....|
00000020  c6 d2 9b 68 70 76 73 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 5c 62  |...hpvs.......\b|
00000030  bb 0d 5a 16 14 ef ee fe  ad b6 1c 86 64 c1 c4 db  |..Z.........d...|
00000040  8b b1 08 15 78 7c 77 95  9f 5d e4 f0 15 72 0b cf  |....x|w..]...r..|
00000050  e7 c1 55 28 65 3f ef 03  13 c6 56 53 ed 54 86 37  |..U(e?....VS.T.7|
00000060  81 ec 53 37 08 97 20 ad  3a bc 76 64 31 5e de d1  |..S7.. .:.vd1^..|
00000070  a2 13 93 55 fe 5c 96 90  f9 d8 0e 03 f7 fd 70 5c  |...U.\........p\|
00000080  de c6 af cc 5c 50 e4 c6  4b 0f 67 47 8a ae ab 3a  |....\P..K.gG...:|
00000090
```

Comment: Looking at a hex dump is going to be more useful than looking at a binary data file with cat. But you should probably just ask whoever you got them from what format they're supposed to be.